# Rails create Tasks for Scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to use the Heroku Rails scheduler.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

I don't know where to write my function that is supposed to be accomplished. Where do I write this?

In their case the function is called `NewsFeed.update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't used that heroku scheduler but i can give you some idea. it is very simple. You just have to write some `worker` or `rake` task. We will use `rake` task. For that you have create file  `lib/tasks/news_feeds_update.rake`

and put this

```
namespace :news_feed do

  task :update => :environment do
    # body of method
    # not sure what you wanted, so i put the below method.
    NewsFeed.update
  end

end
```

Now, you can add this task/method into heroku scheduler . Also you can call this task or method by doing this in command line

```
  rake news_feed:update
```

Comment: I understood this part, but I'm not sure where `Newsfeed.update` should be written. Currently I'm getting an error that `don't know how to build task 'update_api'`

Comment: the only reason why you are seeing that error is because you dont have `update_api` task. Create it like i described above.